# How to improve calculation of position of the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div#panel` which I use to print information about parent elements relative to the element which I clicked on. This means that the div element does not have fixed width and height.

I needed to calculate position for the element div#panel which is positioned using the CSS styles `left` and `top`. My goal is to keep the `div#panel` on the screen, it should not go outside of the current view/screen.

My calculation looks like this:

```
var ClientW = jQuery(window).width();
var ClientH = jQuery(window).height();

var w = $('div#panel').width();
var h = $('div#panel').height();
var offsetY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
var offsetX = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft || 0;
var y, x;
if ( e.clientY > ClientH - h )
  y = offsetY + ClientH - (e.clientY-ClientH);
else
if ( e.clientY < 0 + h )
  y = offsetY + e.clientY + (h-e.clientY);
else
  y = e.clientY < ClientH/2 ? offsetY + e.clientY - h/2 : offsetY + ( e.clientY+h/2 > ClientH-h ? ClientH-h : e.clientY+h/2 ) ;    
x = (e.clientX > ClientW - w/2 )?offsetX + ClientW-w : offsetX + e.clientX;

$('#panel').css({ left: x, top: y })
```

It works almost perfectly, but near the bottom of the client area, just above the bottom scrollbar (20-40px), the element does not fit on the screen. When I click too close to the bottom scrollbar so it will disappear bellow the scrollbar. How could I correct or improve the calculation for the y position?

PS: I do not need to correct x at the moment because the calculation should be similar to y ... later.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found that the problem was in the first condition, not in the last.

```
if ( e.clientY > ClientH - h)
    y = offsetY + e.clientY - h;
else
  if ( e.clientY < 0 + h )
    y = offsetY + e.clientY + (h-e.clientY);
  else
    y = e.clientY < ClientH/2 ? offsetY + e.clientY - h/2 : offsetY + ( e.clientY > ClientH-h? ClientH-h : e.clientY+h/2 ) ;
```

It should be universal solution. Very useful when you need your box fit to the current view.